# Adding paragraph <p> Text to inline-block set of divs puts the div onto the next line

Tags: html, css

When I place any content inside the first div of three below, (which are displayed as inline-block), the first div moves out of position to the next line.

```css
.container-testimonials {
    text-align: center;
    background: teal;
    margin: 20px auto;
    font-size: 0;
}

.clients {
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.clients h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.box8,
.box9,
.box10 {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    width: 31.3%;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 1%;
    background: #F25E5E; 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.box8 p {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-testimonials">
    <div class="clients">
        <h3>WHAT CLIENTS SAY</h3>
    </div> 
    <div class="box8">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box9"></div>
    <div class="box10"></div>
</div>
```

I am fairly sure this has to do with the extra white space the `<p>` tag adds to the width of each div block, which is set to 31.3%, with the other 1% going to padding and the 2/3% going to the other two divs.

Comment: you can solve with `vertical-align:top;`

Answer (score 0):

Adding `vertical-align: top;` to your boxes alignes them on top correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add `vertical-align:top;` on `.box8,.box9,.box10`

```
.box8,
.box9,
.box10 {

    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    width: 31.3%;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 1%;
    background: #F25E5E; 
    vertical-align:top;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/0a94m5tn/1/